# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect()

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I got these error in Codeigniter.

> ```
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect() in
> ```
>
> C:\xampp1\htdocs\CI\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php:92
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp1\htdocs\CI\system\database\DB_driver.php(116):
>   CI_DB_mysql_driver->db_pconnect() #1
>   C:\xampp1\htdocs\CI\system\database\DB.php(149):
>   CI_DB_driver->initialize() #2
>   C:\xampp1\htdocs\CI\system\core\Loader.php(347): DB(Array, NULL) #3
>   C:\xampp1\htdocs\CI\application\models\usermodel.php(7):
>   CI_Loader->database() #4
>   C:\xampp1\htdocs\CI\application\controllers\userscontroller.php(9):
>   UserModel->getUser() #5
>   C:\xampp1\htdocs\CI\system\core\CodeIgniter.php(360):
>   UsersController->index() #6 C:\xampp1\htdocs\CI\index.php(202):
>   require_once('C:\xampp1\htdoc...') #7 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp1\htdocs\CI\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php on
>   line 92

---

**Model class**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class UserModel extends CI_Model
{
    public function getUser()
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from user_accounts");       
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

---

**View class**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>User Accounts</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php foreach($users as $user): ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $user->firstname; ?></td> 
            <td><?= $user->lastname; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

**Controller class**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class UsersController extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('usermodel');

        $data['users'] = $this->usermodel->getUser();

        $this->load->view('user_list',$data);
    }
}
```

---

**database.php**

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;     
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'ci_users';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? The `mysql_` functions were deprecated in PHP 5.5 and completely removed in PHP 7. Also, what version of CodeIgniter?

Comment: What version of CI?

Comment: PHP Version 7.0.13 and CodeIgniter version 2.2.6

Comment: error goon. thanks bro

Answer (score 17):

Because you're using Codeigniter, you're most likely using their Database Class and drivers so you're not using PHP's MySQL functions directly.

Therefore, all you need to do is change

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

to

```
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
```

Comment: say simply change this `$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';` to this `$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';`

Comment: I added the extra info so the OP understands why the other answer is correct but will not work for his particular situation.

Comment: Your answer is correct but its too confusing the core of the  meaning. Add your explain then add something like i added above.

Comment: Ok, I edited it to reflect your suggestion. However, I tend to dislike providing copy/paste solutions as they lead to people not actually learning from their mistakes.

Comment: Cheers for editing to highlight code. I'm on my iPhone so markup isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks Bro. Its Works

Answer (score 3):

In PHP5.6 or higher versions, `mysql_` functions are deprecated and totally removed. Try using `mysqli_` [functions](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: Or try PDO. ;).

Comment: thank you so much alexander bezpuatov its working fine for me thanks a lot.